# Why can GCSfuse not see a GS bucket, when GSutil can?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I am working on a Google Compute instance (Ubuntu), and have previously had success using the GCSfuse utility to mount a storage bucket to a local mount point.

Today I went to do so again, and have been greeted with the following output:

```
Using mount point: /srv/bucket
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: 
setUpBucket: OpenBucket: Unknown bucket "[redacted]"
```

I ran the command `gsutil ls` and the storage bucket is clearly visible in the returned list. I have double and triple checked the spelling of the bucket and cannot find an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. Forgot that you don't need 'gs://' with GCSfuse and it's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Hi @Cam, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @llompalles - I have to wait 2 days to accept the answer apparently